# Lock column width in Excel and allow merging cells

Tags: excel, excel-2013, vba

I try to lock the column width in Excel 2013. My opinion is using "protect sheet" and unchecked "format column". It means that I can lock the column width but I cannot merge cells in this range also.
Whether any solution to lock only the column width? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do only using VBA macro:

```
Sub MyMerge()
  ActiveSheet.Unprotect
  Selection.Merge
  ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True
End Sub
```

If sheet is protected with password, use ***ActiveSheet.Unprotect(Password)***